# Adding Banner Types to Magento

Tags: magento-enterprise, promotions

How would one go about adding additional banner types to Magento?

Currently there are 5, but I'd like to add a couple custom ones

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried Magento Widgets?

Comment: What kind of module are you using for your banners?

Comment: The stock magento module.

Comment: @user9730 There is no Stock module called 'Banners'. Please provide us with a URL path (w/o domain) or the screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are talking about the Magento Enterprise banner functionality.

I'm not sure how I am allowed to share on this since the code is not public. What exactly do you want to achieve with your custom banner type?

For starters, you make the new banner type available in your `config.xml`:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <enterprise>
            <banner>
                <types translate="content footer header leftcol rightcol yourbanner">
                    <yourbanner>Your Banner</yourbanner>
                </types>
            </banner>
        </enterprise>
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: Sorry. Yes it is Enterprise CMS Banners.

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/eJtogdFIPs Here is where you see the banner types. Wanted to add additional types to better organize them as we have many.

Comment: Yes, my code adds the entry to the list.